# Как совместить все шаблоны в 1 стиль

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть код переопределяющий дизайн элемента Menu.

```
<!--Основной стиль меню-->
<Style x:Key="MenuTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#57A0FF" Background="#525457">
                    <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Шаблон для элемента в главном меню с подэлементами-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLevelHeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                   AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" Background="#252626"
                        BorderBrush="Black">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#242424"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--Шаблон для элемента в главном меню без подэлементов-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLevelItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#242424"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--Шаблон для подэлемента меню без подэлементов-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SubmenuItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Shortcut"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0,15,0" x:Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="InputGestureText" Grid.Column="1" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#333333"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--Шаблон для подэлемента меню с подэлементами-->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SubmenuHeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Border">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost" Grid.Column="0" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            <Path Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                  Data="M 0 0 L 0 7 L 4 3.5 Z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
            <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Right" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" HorizontalOffset="10" VerticalOffset="-3"
                   AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="1" Background="#252626" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#333333"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

И есть еще 1 стиль который распределяет шаблоны по нужным элементам меню.

```
<!--Стиль который распределяет шаблоны соответсвутющим элементам-->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TopLevelHeaderTemplate}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role"  Value="TopLevelItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TopLevelItemTemplate}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuHeaderTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SubmenuItemTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Но проблема в том что x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" то есть шаблоны применяется ко всем MenuItem а я бы хотел чтобы шаблоны применялись лишь для 1 меню у которого Style="{StaticResource MenuTemplate}".

Пытался занести этот стиль в ItemContainerStyle но почему то Setter`ы работали кроме тех которые присваивают шаблоны элементам. Да и еще шаблоны применялись только к главным элементам, а к их SubMenu присваивались стандартные значения.

P.s извиняюсь за глупый вопрос

Comment: Именуейте шаблоны своими именами, и не будет проблем с ними. И ещё, зачем вам сеттер на OverridesDefaultStyle, если вы не пепегружаете СТИЛИ?

Comment: а x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" вместо имени стиля это что за финт?

Comment: Так я и назвал своими именами. Я не знаю как правильно все в 1 стиль засунуть (главный стиль меню) чтобы не пришлой каждому Item писать Style а лучше Menu стиль прописать и все Item будут тоже со стилями.

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось куда проще

```
<Style.Resources>
        <!--Стиль который распределяет шаблоны соответсвутющим элементам-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource TopLevelHeaderTemplate}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role"  Value="TopLevelItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource TopLevelItemTemplate}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#E6E6E6"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuHeaderTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
```